# Summing some of the elements of a Numpy array

Tags: python

I am looking for an efficient Python - Numpy solution.

In an intensive computational job, I want to add the elements of each row of a 2D array from the first element of each row up to element n where n <  than the number of elements composing the rows. I want to store the result of each such sums concerning each particular row.

Comment: See [ask] and add a [mcve]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try numpy.sum() on a slice of your 2D array:

```
n = 1
array = numpy.array([
                     [0, 1, 2],
                     [3, 4, 5],
                    ])
sum_upto_n = numpy.sum(array[:, :n], axis=1)
# sum_upto_n: [1, 7]
```